# SQL query with HAVING min/max returns fewer rows than without

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query something like this:

```
SELECT A.*, C.value
FROM A
JOIN B ON B.group = A.group
JOIN C ON C.a = A.id
GROUP BY A.group
```

This query returns a certain number of rows. Because of the GROUP BY, I'm trying to specify which row I want if there are multiple with the same value for `A.group` - so I've added a HAVING clause:

```
SELECT A.*, C.value
FROM A
JOIN B ON B.group = A.group
JOIN C ON C.a = A.id
GROUP BY A.group
HAVING C.value = MIN(C.value)
```

My understanding was that MySQL should first apply all the joins and other conditions and then do the grouping. And since I'm simply asking for the row with the minimum `C.value`, the grouping should not eliminate any cases.

But the latter query returns less rows than the former. Why is that and how can I achieve the desired behavior?

(The server is running MySQL 5.1)

Comment: While this is allowed by `MySQL`, not adding all of the non-aggregate columns to the `GROUP BY` will lead to unpredictable results, and is not advised.

Comment: Your statement "multiple with the same value for A.group" does not make sense, you are grouping by that value right? there should be only one row in the result.

Comment: *query with HAVING min/max returns fewer rows than without* -  Because `having` usually exclude rows

Comment: *"since I'm simply asking for the row with the minimum C.value"* -- this is not a job for `GROUP BY`. `GROUP BY` doesn't return rows from the tables involved in the query. It generates new rows using the data retrieved by the `FROM/WHERE` part of the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My understanding was that MySQL should first apply all the joins and
>   other conditions and then do the grouping. And since I'm simply asking
>   for the row with the minimum C.value, the grouping should not
>   eliminate any cases.
>
> But the latter query returns less rows than the former. Why is that
>   and how can I achieve the desired behavior?

What you say is true -- but the "having" has no effect until after the grouping is resolved.  By adding `HAVING C.value = MIN(C.value)` **to any query** you are saying do everything in that query and then only return the result that have a min value of C.  This HAVING statement will always return less (or equal) number of rows.

Comment: Seems like just I misunderstood how HAVING and GROUP BY work together, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the main problem you're seeing in your query is that you're getting multiple `A.Group` results coming back.  This is because you are only adding the `A.Group` column to the `GROUP BY`, but you're `SELECT`ing `A.*` (which also includes the `ID` of `A`).  Doing this would lead to some results like the following:

```
A.Id     A.Group    C.Value
1        1          1
2        1          2
3        2          1
4        3          1
5        3          2
```

[This is allowed in `MySQL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html), but it is not advised, as it leads to unpredictable results.

As I understand your question, you're looking for results more like this, instead:

```
A.Group    C.Value
1          1
2          1
3          1
```

The fix to get your desired results is simple:  `SELECT` the `MIN(C.Value)` and only select `A.Group`:

```
SELECT A.Group, MIN(C.value)
FROM   A
JOIN   B ON B.group = A.group
JOIN   C ON C.a = A.id
GROUP BY A.group
```

> But the latter query returns less rows than the former. Why is that and how can I achieve the desired behavior?

It will naturally return fewer records, as you are *limiting* the results.